# How can I merge multiple ebooks in a single file?

Tags: epub, calibre, editing, sigil

Is there a way to easily combine multiple ebooks into a single file, that will collect all of them?

Comment: Related: http://ebooks.stackexchange.com/q/1069/136

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is it possible to use a full fledged editor like [Sigil](https://code.google.com/p/sigil/). It works with `.epub` files, but if needed, before the editing, it's possible to use [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/) to convert the source ebook into `.epub`, then reconvert it after the job.

Anyway, for a faster and easier solution, Calibre has a very useful additional plugin called [EpubMerge](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=169744), that, as the name imply, can merge multiple epubs into a single one, also letting create a new table of contents and edit all relevant metadata of the new output file, while leaving unaltered the source ones. Also in this case, if another ebook format is needed, a conversion is required after the editing since the plugin only works with `.epub` files.

[image]

Comment: So how is the TOC addressed then?

Comment: The TOC is created by merging the existing ones. Optionally, Calibre can also be used to customize it.

Comment: updated link for Sigil since code.google.com is long gone: [https://github.com/Sigil-Ebook/Sigil](https://github.com/Sigil-Ebook/Sigil). If you are on Linux, it might even already be in your central repos (It was for Fedora 35)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming all files and only those files are in one directory.

For PDF files:

```
pdftk *.pdf cat output ../combined.pdf
```

For DjVu:

```
djvm  -create *.djvu ../combined.djvu
```

Of course you would have to resolve metadata (author of a combined document) yourself.

Comment: Maybe a little more content here on where you would run this command?  Are you doing this on an ereader, Windows folder, Apple...?

Comment: @JamesJenkins that would best executed through a Linux terminal. A good reference: ["How do I install Pdftk on my server?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146766/how-do-i-install-pdftk-on-my-server) there is a graphical tool: [PDFtk Free](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/)

Comment: @Gramps You can use it on Windows as well, and on [OSX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20804441/how-do-i-installing-pdftk-on-mac)

Comment: Really like this strategy... I've been having a time trying to merge several hundred html files into a single epub. Calibre's `ebook-convert` lets me do this for a 1:1 conversion but doesn't seem to accept multiple input files. There is Calibre Merger Plugin but it appears to only work for graphical mode making it a no-go for scripting ~800 html pages into a single file... With this, I can programmatically convert html to pdf (via `ebook-convert`), merge multiple pdfs into one with the above, and then convert the final pdf back to epub with one more `ebook-convert` call.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Calibre Merger Plugin** , I think.

For details, click to [***how-to-merge-multiple-epub-ebooks***](http://www.epubor.com/how-to-merge-multiple-epub-ebooks.html)

Comment: Ideally you should summarize the steps in your answer (and leave the link). Link-only answers are generally frowned up (especially if the site is down or the link dies for whatever reason).